# notification's vibrate and sound defaults are working as INSISTENT

Tags: android

When an event happens my handler calls my eventAlert() function that pops up a new notification. It doesnt matter if it is set with default flags or with custom sound, when notifiing comes the sound repeats itself just like with FLAG_INSISTENT. Even with FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE. If i specify a custom sound with Uri.parse it behaves the same way. All the same with vibration. However if a  make a custom vibration, calling it with the Vibrator's vibreate(long[], int) function it only vibrates once as it should. What am i doing wrong, what is the most common mistake that leads here? How can i make it to vibrate and alert with sound only once? My eventAlert() is called once, im pretty sure. thx for your help!

Comment: Ok, this only happens when DEFAULT_LIGHTS is also set. When DEFAULT_VIBRATE and DEFAULT_SOUND are set only (but DEFAULT_LIGHTS is not), it works as it should, not repeating. So using FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS instead of DEFAULT_LIGHT as a workaround now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, this piece of code is what most of us search for when creating notifications for first time:

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL clears the notification from the notification bar/list when clicking it.